# Web Browser Control communicating with application

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services, webbrowser-control, com-interop

I am not sure whether this is a right question!! Its just a scenario I would like to know whether the implementation is possible.

I have a WPF application having a web browser control which loads SQL reports. We configure the Reports Url to WPF browser thus when loading the browser control loads reports. This is pretty straight forward. We are now planning to load the data that we get in the web browser control(I mean the reports data) to some control in wpf application. Lets say from Web browser control to some datagrid.

Please some one clarify if this is possible,, by what means.

Thank you.

Comment: If you host the webbrowser control, you have access to the html being rendered. Is the report just plain html?

Comment: Yes a simple sql report having some control in it which displays data.

Comment: @Darey, this implementation is possible. Is it the right way to deal with your data? I don't think so. Why not to populate your *some other control* directly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Noseratio, enduser would select required information he needs from hundreds of reports. So, I need to implement a way where I can communicate back to client from web browser control. Thanks.

Comment: I tried by invoking C# through Javascript, but it doesn't seem to be best approach since it makes tight coupling between web page and code, where we cannot ask reports developers to insert required javascripts.